# what's the difference between receiver and action in eos contract?

Tags: smart-contract

`void apply( uint64_t receiver, uint64_t code, uint64_t action )`

What's the difference between receiver and action in eos contract?

Comment: Why not adopt the answer below?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This page](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-cpp/docs/communication-model#section-action-handlers-and-action-apply-context) in the official documentation should help answer this:

[image: diagram]

> From a global view of an EOSIO blockchain, every node in the EOSIO
>   network gets a copy of and runs every action in every contract. Some
>   of the nodes are doing the actual work of the contract, while others
>   are processing in order to prove the validity of the transaction
>   blocks. It is, therefore, important that contracts be able to
>   determine "who they are", or basically, under which context are they
>   running. Context identification information is provided in the action
>   context, as illustrated in the above diagram by `receiver`, `code`,
>   `action`. `receiver` is the account that is currently processing the
>   action. `code` is the account that authorized the contract. `action` is
>   the ID of the currently running action.

Comment: The wiki is deprecated. Could you please add the answer here?

Comment: Updated the answer to fix URL and include content

Answer (score 2):

`Receiver` is executing contract.
`Code` is namespace of action event.
`Action` is name of the function to execute.